# How to update a nested field in firestore using node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

How to update the child in firestore using node.js ?
Here is my data :

```
{  firstName : "youg",
   id: 9,
   lastName : "Nue",
   room : {
     floor : 14,
     no : 103  
     temp : 50
  }
}
```

I tried update, but failed :

```
const studentId = '1tqfC07qO8zrVApOYVSU';
await db.collection('students').doc(studentId).update( {
    'room\floor'  : '12'
    }
);
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a nested field you need to use a `.` in its name. So:

```
db.collection('students').doc(studentId).update({
  'room.floor'  : '12'
});
```

Also see the documentation on [updating fields in a nested object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).